# include() not picking up previously defined variables

Tags: php

I'm pretty sure I just need a good ol` fashion brain check. I have never seen such a silly issue and I'm sure I just missed something dumb.

**index.php**

```
<?
require('lib/conf.php');

/* bunch of code here */

echo get_user('username',$_SESSION['uid']);
```

**lib/conf.php**

```
<?
/* bunch of secret stuff here */

$dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);  
////////////
//
// Includes / Requirements
//
////////////
include('functions/user.functions.php');
```

**functions/user.functions.php**

```
<?
function get_user($dvar,$uid){
    $psql = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT :dvar FROM ls_users WHERE uid=:uid");
    $dbcon->beginTransaction();
    $psql->execute(array(":dvar"=>$dvar,":uid"=>$uid));
    foreach($psql as $row){ return $row[$dvar]; }
}
```

However attempting to do such a simple thing, I continue to get:

```
Undefined variable: dbcon in <b>/home/lodestar/public_html/lib/functions/user.functions.php</b> on line <b>10</b>

Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in <b>/home/lodestar/public_html/lib/functions/user.functions.php</b> on line <b>9
```

So, now that I feel as though I'm going crazy could you please check my brain and tell me what I'm missing?

**NOTES**

*Line number in error will not reflect the correct line number in example code*

Comment: call the global variable to declare the global variable in function  use `function get_user($dvar,$uid){ global $dbcon; ..... }`

Comment: You have a variable scope problem: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Should I be required to tell the system it is a global variable even if it not being used _inside_ of a method or class?

Comment: @TamilSelvan you were correct, I didn't know you had to specify global when using functions as-well as classes and methods. Thank you. Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark as solved. Or We could vote to close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the global variable to declare the global variable in function use

`function get_user($dvar,$uid){ global $dbcon; ..... }`

Comment: as soon as the pesky 10 minute wait time is up, I will gladly mark as solved. Thanks again! I do not remember having to do this on different servers. Is there a PHP setting that turns this global requirement off? Register Globals perhaps?